What is the creditor priority of stolen property in bankruptcy proceedings?
In bankruptcy, a large number of hands fight to take slices from a small pie. The Absolute Priority Rule specifies that creditors are paid following a predetermined order based on the type of their debt, with the order terminating when the pie is exhausted. First is secured claims, next unsecured, next preferred equity, finally common equity, though the court can impose super priority status to loans given to increase the value of the assets.
But what about these three cases:

The company physically stole assets from another party (i.e. "theft")
The company fraudulently obtained assets from another party (i.e. "selling the Brooklyn Bridge")
The company obtained assets under contract, did not meet its obligations under the terms of that contract, and is no longer capable of specific performance


In #3, I would guess it matters what the contract says about those assets. If they pre-paid for the performance, and it says they must return the payment if they can't perform, it seems like it would be like any other claim of money owed.


The Absolute Priority Rule specifies that creditors are paid following
a predetermined order based on the type of their debt, with the order
terminating when the pie is exhausted. First is secured claims, next
unsecured, next preferred equity, finally common equity, though the
court can impose super priority status to loans given to increase the
value of the assets.

Close, but incomplete. Within unsecured claims that are ten priorities set forth at 11 U.S.C. § 507 (none of which apply here).
A claim or money damages for theft or fraud (e.g. if the stolen asset cannot be located) is an unsecured claim in bankruptcy. And, generally speaking it won't be a priority claim (the main exception would be wage theft, which would be a fourth priority unsecured claim).
A money damages claim for theft or fraud is non-dischargeable in bankruptcy, pursuant to 11 U.S.C. § 523 (if the non-dischargeability issue is raised in a timely adversary proceeding in the bankruptcy case, which is a very strict deadline), so it will survive the end of the bankruptcy case. But during the bankruptcy the distribution that will be paid by the debtor to the money damages for theft credit is a general non-priority unsecured debt.
In the case of a corporation in liquidation, the inability to discharge the debt won't matter because there will be no post-bankruptcy assets and because corporation's debts aren't discharged in a liquidating bankruptcy. In the case of a reorganizing corporation, however, the non-dischargeable debt should survive the reorganization.
But in the case of an individual with future earnings potential, a non-dischargeable debt can be collected from the individual's future income as well as from the bankruptcy estate.

The company obtained assets under contract, did not meet its
obligations under the terms of that contract, and is no longer capable
of specific performance

This is a general non-priority unsecured debt, and unlike the debts for theft or fraud, it can be discharged in bankruptcy.

Let me see if I understand this correctly. In both of the first two cases, fraud and theft, the debt isn't dischargeable in bankruptcy, but is sufficiently low in priority that there's a reasonable likelihood the entity's assets won't suffice to pay the debt before the entity is liquidated. If the entity is not liquidated, whatever remains of the debt after distributions will survive to be paid back another day, assuming the reorganized entity is revenue-generating. For the final case, failing to meet contractual obligations, it's just low-priority dischargeable debt. Is that right?

@TheEnvironmentalist That's a decent summary. It is also worth noting that a large percentage of small business bankruptcies that start out a reorganizations are ultimately converted to liquidations, especially retail businesses, and that in small business reorganizations the most common outcome is that priority tax debts take all or more of the available assets leaving little or nothing for general non-priority creditors as a result of the BK process. Big business bankruptcies (especially for non-retail firms), however, often successfully reorganize and often pay a decent % of debts back.

If the theft is of identifiable physical property, is the victim able to recover that or is it liquidated for the benefit of creditors?

@DaleM The victim can recover it.
